# How do i get a data from JSON server response in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm sending a JSON request in PHP and i get a response from the server, that looks like this:

```
{"success":true,"result":
{"items":
[{"woj":"łódzkie","powiat":"kutnowski","gmina":"Bedlno","kod":"99-        
311","miasto":"Adamów","id":"99-311Adamów167271172700"}]},
"error":null,
"unAuthorizedRequest":false}
```

I want to pick a content from "woj" and "powiat" but it doesn't work.

My code looks like this:

```
$code = 'https://hetman.e4b.com.pl/api/services/app/kodPoczt/KodPocztInfo? 
 kod='.$kod;
 $ch = curl_init();
 //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $code);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
 //execute post
 $result1 = curl_exec($ch);
 //close connection
 curl_close($ch);
 echo $result1;
 $wynik  = json_decode($result1, true);
 echo $wynik['result'][0]['woj'];
```

Comment: Your string is not valid json.

Comment: it is - you just have to remove some whitespaces @Andreas - anyway his echo at end is wrong

Comment: If you need to remove something to make it work/valid doesn't that mean it's invalid before the change? Why post a Json with spaces that makes it invalid in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

show your full code... curl isnt inited in your example and return_transfer isnt set. whats the output of $result1?

anyway its

```
$wynik['result']['items'][0]['woj'];
```

Answer (score 0):

$temp = '{
                    "success": true,
                    "result": {
                        "items": [{
                            "woj": "łódzkie",
                            "powiat": "kutnowski",
                            "gmina": "Bedlno",
                            "kod": "99-311",
                            "miasto": "Adamów",
                            "id": "99-311Adamów167271172700"
                        }]
                    },
                    "error": null,
                    "unAuthorizedRequest": false
                }';

```
    $result = json_decode($temp,true);
    echo $result['result']['items'][0]['woj'];
```